# Pinch to Zoom not working in MapView when too small

Tags: android, touch, zooming, android-mapview, pinch

So i set up a MapView and enabled zoom controls. When the map spans the whole screen (different Activity) it supports pinch to zoom just fine.

On Another Activity i display a rather small map and i noticed that pinch to zoom doesn't work there (only the zoom icons).

I played around a bit and noticed that once the map is smaller than half of the screen-width (round about..) pinch to zoom stops working. I guess that this is a feature of MapView, as pinch to zoom doesn't make sense when the view is to small.

I couldn't find this documented anywhere and couldn't find a way to force keeping pinch to zoom enabled, even if the view is rather small...

Comment: Are you using mapview inside ScrollView or ListView?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure about that, as it's so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. On screens with big header and small map multitouch doesnt work (or work in incorrect way). I noticed that with big footer and small map everything works perfectly! To solve the problem I used full screen map and Relative layout to add necessary ui components covering the map.